# EF6 - Invalid cast from decimal to int32

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have some table with a field defined like...

```
...
[oneField] NUMERIC(2) NULL,
...
```

And the corresponding c# entity model...

```
...
public int? oneField { get; set; }
...
```

Fluent configuration...

```
Property(r => r.oneField)
    .HasColumnName("oneField");
```

Well, with all this above, I'm getting the following exception when retrieving data from the DB..

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The specified cast from a materialized
  'System.Decimal' type to a nullable 'System.Int32' type is not valid.
```

Any ideas to fix this? I could understand that if the NUMERIC field would have a decimal part that might cause the problem, but being just an integer value of 2 digits, why cannot be casted into an INT32?

Note: I know that if I change the field in the table to be an INT problem will be solved, but I'd like to keep the NUMERIC(2), as represents better the values that are to be stored there (Numbers with 2 digits).

Comment: `NUMERIC(2)` is effectively a synonym for `DECIMAL(2)` (assuming you're using SQL Server here because you haven't specified) so why is your model using an `int`? You say you want to keep the incompatible types but there's no reason to do that at all.

Comment: The value to be stored there is an integer value with 2 digits, so I think NUMERIC(2) represents that better.  At the model, I'd like to use an INT type as it's a more simple type.  No calculations are to be made with that field, so I think it's a better type than decimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `NUMERIC(2)` then you need a `decimal` model property otherwise you will see the conversion errors that you report. So your solution is to change the database or change your model.

However, `NUMERIC(2)` is overkill for your purpose and will consume 5 bytes where you only want numbers up to 99. Instead you should consider using a [`TINYINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which will allow you to store numbers from 0 to 255. That would mean the storage is only a single byte and your model could be `byte` to match.

Comment: You are absolutely right about NUMERIC(2) being overkill.  Didn't realize that it's going to take 5 bytes.  So, probably your proposal is the best to align as much as possible to the values to be stored.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, it tells you that the column was materialized into a `System.Decimal` object and you're trying to cast it to a `System.Int32` object which is not supported. Try using INTEGER to define your database column

Or alternatively using `System.Decimal` to define your EF object

Comment: Did you even read the OPs question? In particular the Note-part?

Comment: He added that note after I started replying :) anyway, last part of my answer should do.

Comment: Yes, I know that if I change either to INT at that table or Decimal on the model, problem would be fixed, but I'd like to keep those.

Comment: Well then that's more of a design question. the cast from the db to the model should be either int->int or decimal->decimal. If you need another data type to be accessible from your model, you can make a property which casts it into `int`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you want it, here is your model:

```
internal decimal? OneFieldIntenal { get; set; }
public int? OneField
{
    get => OneFieldIntenal.HasValue ? (int)OneFieldIntenal.Value : null;
    set => OneFieldIntenal = value;
}
```

Here is your mapping:

```
Property(r => r.OneFieldIntenal)
    .HasColumnName("oneField");
```

But only use this if you **ABSOLUTELY** sure what are you doing and you need to keep you type mismatch. This solution is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using sql server. Here are the .NET integer types and maximum fitting numeric types:

- `SByte` => -128 to 127 which fits up to `NUMERIC(2)`
- `Int16` => -32,768 to 32,767 which fits up to `NUMERIC(4)`
- `Int32` => -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 which fits up to `NUMERIC(9)`
- `Int64` => -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 which fits up to `NUMERIC(18)`
- `decimal` can hold up to 7.9*10^28 to `NUMERIC(28)`.

The problem is i doubt EF isnt going to like your conversion, since you are coding DB first and don't want to change anything, i think the only thing you can do is accept it for decimal and cast it client side.